# reference for homology complex projective space

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I am looking for references on homology complex projective spaces; or more precisely the classification (if any) of smooth oriented manifolds which have the same homology groups as $\mathbb{CP}^n$.

Comment: The connected sum of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ with any homology sphere will be such a manifold, but there could be others. I don't know what kind of classification you can hope for.

Comment: It will contain at least all these: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_complex_projective_spaces